# Question about Measure theory. The least $\sigma$- algebra generated by certain subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ equals the Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory

I would appreciate any help with the following exercise:

Consider the collection $F_0$ of subsets of the real numbers that can be written as a finite union of disjoint intervals of type: $(a,b]$: $-\infty \leq a\leq b\leq\infty$ or $(a,\infty)$. Show that $F_0$ is an algebra and that $\sigma(F_0)=B(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F_0\subset \mathbb{B}(R)$, we have $\sigma (F_0)\subset \mathbb{B}(R)$. Conversely, note that every open interval is in $\sigma(F_0)$, then  $\sigma(F_0)\supset \mathbb{B}(R)$.