# where is the empty set in this algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

For $a<b \in \mathbb{R} $, let us consider the collection $I$ of all left-open, right-closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. That is, we have the collection of all the following intervals: $(a,b],(-\infty,b],(a,+\infty), (-\infty,+\infty)$.

Let us consider the following class:

$\mathscr{F}(I):=\{E \subseteq \mathbb{R}: E=\bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k, I_k\in I, \text{and } I_k\cap I_l=\varnothing \text{  for }1\leq k\neq l\leq n, n\in\mathbb{N} \}$

I have read that this is an algebra, but where is the empty set in this class? Even considering $a\leq b$, I cannot undesrtand the claim. Am I missing something?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If we take $n = 0$, don't we get the empty set?

Comment: Isn't $(5, 5]$ empty?  Isn't it the set of all numbers simultaneously greater than $5$ and less than or equal to $5$?

Comment: @KennyWong: I suspect $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$ for the OP.  That's the more common interpretation.

Comment: But we need $a < b$ in $(a,b]$.

Comment: What does the first paragraph of this question have to do with the rest? It asks us to think of a certain collection, but it doesn't give that collection a name, and it does not seem to be mentioned ever after.

Comment: But @BrianTung, a<b so it is not posible 5<5, isn`t it?

Comment: I have edited a bit the question @HenningMakholm. Sorry I am not an expert mathematician.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas: You either have to allow $a \le b$, or allow $n$ to be $0$ (implying that $\cup _{n=1} ^0$ is the empty union) - without any of these, there is no $\emptyset$ in $\mathscr F (I)$.

Comment: I have read this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938880/question-about-measure-theory-the-least-sigma-algebra-generated-by-certain) and I can see the differences, maybe the initial condition a<b is not correct. Any further idea.

Comment: Yes @AlexM., those are my suspicions.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas: Sorry, I did not see $a < b$.